# Pasar a el form un List<Objeto> desde JS a Servidor

Tags: javascript, java-ee, arraylist, spring-boot, lista

Tengo un formulario en una pagina web al que desde JS recojo unos valores y los añado aun objeto. Todos esos objetos los meto dentro de un array y lo añado a un input hidden que tengo en la pagina:

```
document.editRouteForm.busStops.value = JSON.stringify(getBusStopsPoints());

 var getBusStopsPoints = function () {
        var arrayPos = 0;
        busStops.map(function (marker) {
            //Recogemos las rutas
            busStopsObj.lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
            busStopsObj.lng = marker.getPosition().lng();

            //Recogemos la descripcion
            busStopsObj.description = busStopsInfo[arrayPos];
            arrayPos++;

            console.log("arrayPos: " + arrayPos);
            busStopsForm.push(busStopsObj);
        });

        console.log(busStopsForm);
    };
```

La salida que obtengo es la siguiente:

```
[
   {
      "lat":43.4721537946863,
      "lng":-3.8495182526509097,
      "description":"2"
   },
   {
      "lat":43.4721537946863,
      "lng":-3.8495182526509097,
      "description":"2"
   },
   {
      "lat":43.4721537946863,
      "lng":-3.8495182526509097,
      "description":"2"
   }
]
```

Ahora en el servidor me llega como null y me da una excepcion:

> [Field error in object 'route' on field 'busStops': rejected value [undefined]; codes [typeMismatch.route.busStops,typeMismatch.busStops,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [route.busStops,busStops]; arguments []; default message [busStops]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'busStops'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'es.ticnor.trayecbus.model.BusStop' for property 'busStops[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]

Estoy tratando de añadir los valores de un objeto en el back-end con los datos que me llega del front. Uno de esos valores es un List<> de otro objeto. Que es donde el servidor me da la excepcion.

```
private final List<BusStop> busStops = new ArrayList<>();
```

Y el objeto lo forman estos campos:
    public class BusStop extends BaseEntity {

```
private String description;

private float lat;

private float lng;
```

El formulario funciona y los parámetros le llegan salvo ese campo que al parecer no se corresponde con lo esperado (un ArrayList de objets). Entonces alguien sabe por que me da este fallo? Acaso no corresponde la salida que obtengo desde el formulario con el esperado en el servidor?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te dice que estás tratando de convertir una `String` en una `List<BusStop>`:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'es.ticnor.trayecbus.model.BusStop'
```

Si estás pasando una `String` en formato `JSON` al `@Controller`, utiliza un parser como Jackson para procesarla y convertirla al objeto o lista de objetos que deseas.

Con el `JSON` que envías al `@Controller`:

```
[
   {
      "lat":43.4721537946863,
      "lng":-3.8495182526509097,
      "description":"2"
   },
   {
      "lat":43.4721537946863,
      "lng":-3.8495182526509097,
      "description":"2"
   },
   {
      "lat":43.4721537946863,
      "lng":-3.8495182526509097,
      "description":"2"
   }
]
```

Suponiendo que tienes una clase llamada BusStop:

```
public class BusStop {

    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private String description;
    public BusStop() {

    }

    public BusStop(double lat, double lng, String description) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.description = description;
    }

    //getters and setters ....    
}
```

En esta clase hago el procesado:

```
package com.so.victor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class TestSO {

    private static String json = "[{\"lat\":43.4721537946863,\"lng\":-3.8495182526509097,\"description\":\"2\"},{\"lat\":43.4721537946863,\"lng\":-3.8495182526509097,\"description\":\"2\"},{\"lat\":43.4721537946863,\"lng\":-3.8495182526509097,\"description\":\"2\"}]";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BusStop> mylist = convertBusStop();

        mylist.forEach(c -> {
            System.out.println(c.getLat());
        });
    }

    private static List<BusStop> convertBusStop() {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<BusStop> myObjects = null;
        try {
            myObjects = mapper.readValue(json,
                    mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, BusStop.class));
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return myObjects;

    }
}
```

He utilizado esta versión de jackson:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Entonces en que formato debo devolverle la petición al servidor? Ahora mismo era un String con el formato que aparece en la imagen. En que formato deberia formatear el JSON? https://imgur.com/a/IeocS9t

Comment: Supongo que no hay ningún problema en enviarle un JSON al servidor, lo único es que luego debes hacer parsing y convertirlo al objeto que quieres. Escribe el JSON que le envías al servidor para verlo.

Comment: Yo lo convertia asi. "document.editRouteForm.busStops.value = JSON.stringify(getBusStopsPoints());" . Como deberia de hacer ahora?

Comment: Me refiero a convertirlo una vez llega al `@Controller`, ahí es donde debes convertir ese JSON String que envías

Comment: Comprendo. Voy a intentarlo.

Comment: Muestra el JSON, a lo mejor puedo ayudar

Comment: [{"lat":43.4721537946863,"lng":-3.8495182526509097,"description":"2"},{"lat":43.4721537946863,"lng":-3.8495182526509097,"description":"2"},{"lat":43.4721537946863,"lng":-3.8495182526509097,"description":"2"}]

Comment: Voy a editar la respuesta con las clases, pero debes poner este `JSON` en tu pregunta para dar contexto y que se vea de donde ha salido esta respuesta

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y por la clara solución amigo me funciono perfectamente. He editado la pregunta con el JSON de salida.